# Get index of first "true" in vector

Tags: vector, opencl

How do I efficiently calculate the index of the first "true" value in an OpenCL vector:

```
float4 f = (float4)(1, 2, 3, 4);
int i = firstTrue(f > 2);
```

In the example I would like to get `i=2` because 3 is the first value greater than 2.

I have looked at all functions in http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/ but have found nothing.

Is this such an uncommon operation?
How do I calculate this (on my own) without much branching/code duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built-in function that does exactly what you want, but I have some ideas on how you could do it. There might be a simpler solution, but I've only had one cup of coffee so far. The idea is to leverage the "count leading zeros" function "clz". You just need to convert the results of your conditional into bit positions in an integer.

1. Create a boolean vector with true/false state set by the comparison
2. Do a dot product of that against an integer vector with pre-defined values that correspond to bit positions.
3. The first bit set will correspond to the index you're asking for. Use clz() or a bithack to find that bit index.

In code, something like this (untested and might need adjusting):

```
float4 f = (float4)(1, 2, 3, 4);
int4 greater = (f > 2);
int4 bits = (int4)(8, 4, 2, 1);
int sum = dot(greater, bits); // maybe this needs to use float
int index = clz(sum); // might need offset applied
```

You'll need to offset or invert the result from clz to get 0,1,2,3 but that's just addition or subtraction.

### Working Code

```
int firstTrue(int4 v) {
    return 4 - (clz(0) - clz((v.x & 8) | (v.y & 4) | (v.z & 2) | (v.w & 1));
}
```

Comment: Hm, the compiler gives me an error on the dot function and lists only overloads for `floatn` and `doublen` it seems the dot function cannot be applied to integer vectors.

Comment: I was thinking that might be the case. You can up-convert to float and then back to an int before using clz. Or write the dot product yourself (sum of products of members).

Comment: Very clever way of solving the issue saving some instructions.

Comment: Note: `For scalar types, the relational operators shall return 0
if the specified relation is false and 1 if the specified relation is true. For vector types, the relational operators shall return 0 if the specified relation is false and -1 (i.e. all bits set) if the specified relation is true.` (http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf#page=218 end of part d)

Comment: I was thinking more about this, and realized the dot product isn't needed. You can just use "clz" on the "int4 greater" and divide the result by sizeof(int) to get the index of the first true element.

Comment: @Dithermaster: clz on the int4 will result in another int4 (because it works component wise). I have come up with following solution: `4 - (clz(0) - clz((greater.x & 8) | (greater.y & 4) | (greater.z & 2) | (greater.z & 1)))`. It is somewhat more robust to erratic values in greater and relies on the fact that true=-1 (all bits set) and false=0 (no bit set).

Comment: @Nobody: good catch on the int4 component-wise issue, and your solution looks nice. Thanks for sharing it.